# Re-subscribing to events after disconnect/reconnect in SignalR 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, signalr

#### The problem

I have a .NET Client application that makes use of [HubConnectionManager](https://github.com/killnine/HubConnectionManager/blob/master/HubConnectionManager/HubConnectionManager.cs) to retry connecting to the server if my app changes to the Closed state.

It seems to work great in the following instances:

1. For short disconnects (e.g. restarting the SignalR server) it immediately reconnects and picks up where it left off.
2. For longer disconnects (if the server is down for more than 30 seconds), it will go from connected->reconnecting->disconnected and then connect again just fine.

*HOWEVER*, in case (2), while the client has successfully reconnected, none of the events that the client previously subscribed to come through anymore. So, in effect, the client is connected but effectively dead.

#### What I've Tried

So reconnecting works in all cases, but if I reconnect after a disconnect I lose my subscriptions.

Therefore, I initially tried to capture the `StateChanged` event and, upon changing from `Connecting` to `Connected`, re-subscribe to the server's broadcasts (e.g. `_hubProxy.On<MachineStatusDto>(UPDATE_MACHINE_STATUS, BroadcastMachineStatus);`). However, this doesn't appear to work and I am concerned that, if I am not careful, I could create memory leaks just like subscribing using `+=` multiple times.

Not sure where to go from here...

#### Misc. Details

- The client is WPF (.NET 4 compatible)
- The server is a Windows Service self-hosting SignalR (skys-the-limit .NET 4.5.2)
- Client and Server are in the same building, infinite retry on connections is A-OK.
- This is for an internal LoB app, so broad use across the internet and such isn't a requirement

Comment: We had a similar problem with .Net remoting. Can you try "rebooting" further down in the communication stack? Maybe on the transport level? Something like, destroy and re-create the client.

Comment: I figured out the issue: I had to do more with losing Group memberships after a disconnect. See answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further investigation, and running my own Client/Server on HubConnectionManager, I realized that  I *am* actually reconnecting and receiving subscriptions afterwards.

The caveat with my LoB application is that my subscriptions are based on a Group membership. According to MSDN:

> "When reconnecting after a temporary disruption, the user
>   automatically re-joins the previously-assigned groups. Automatically
>   rejoining a group only applies when reconnecting, **not when
>   establishing a new connection**."

Therefore, I was reconnecting successfully and would have received any global messages sent by the server. However, I have to re-add my clients to their respective `Group` when re-establishing a connection after a `DisconnectTimeout`.

Here's the code I use:

```
//Somewhere when initializing the connection
_hubConnectionManager.StateChanged += OnHubConnectionManagerOnStateChanged;

//Handler for state change
private void OnHubConnectionManagerOnStateChanged(StateChange st)
{
    //When disconnected, set state variable
    if (st.NewState == ConnectionState.Disconnected)
    {
        _wasDisconnected = true;
    }

    //If disconnected and we re-create connection successfully, re-subscribe to updates.
    if (_wasDisconnected && st.OldState == ConnectionState.Connecting && st.NewState == ConnectionState.Connected)
    {
        SubscribeToMachine(MachineStatusDetails.MachineId);
    }

    Messenger.Default.Send<ConnectionState>(st.NewState, UIMessageToken.ConnectionState);
}
```